# Getting uninitialized constant Spree::Admin::UserSessionsController when trying to access admin in fresh install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, solidus

I've done a fresh install of ruby on rails and solidus with WSL using ubuntu.

I can access the frontend store just fine, see the default products and such, but when I try to access the admin page using http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/login I get the following error:

[image]

I tried searching for it but got nowhere, these are some specs of my system:

ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v
Rails 7.0.5

I've trying searching for the same error online but got no clear answer, i'm expecting that the admin page begins working.

EDIT:

So the steps I did to install solidus is exactly what it is described in their github, nothing more, nothing less

I ran these commands in sequence:

```
rails new my_store

bundle add solidus

bin/rails g solidus:install

bin/rails s
```

I can access the frontend of the store just fine using localhost, but when I try to access /admin is when I encounter the error, Ive tried using windows, and then WSL with ubuntu, got same error on both.

dont have another machine to test it rn.

here's a copy of the error as plain text:

https://pastebin.com/qbcqVq7d

```
its on pastebin because it exceeds the 30k characters limit.
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't seem like a "specs of system" type of problem. it's more a "What did I do wrong?" sort.

Comment: Did this route work on another machine?

Comment: Hello tadman, thanks for the answer i`ve published the whole error as plaintext on pastebin, also, described everything that I did until I got the error, I hope that it clears everything for you, again, thanks for the help :)